# Initialize map issues

Tags: go

I am developing a project where I need to declare the following:

```
mapDataPayload := make(map[string][]*dataPayload)
```

If I **append** data to it, it works normally.

```
mapDataPayload := make(map[string][]*dataPayload)

for {
    select {
    case rcvData := <-ch:

        mapDataPayload[rcvData.Topic] = append(
            mapDataPayload[rcvData.Topic],
            &dataPayload{Message: rcvData.Message},
        )
    }
}
```

However, I would like to set a limit in size. With append it grows without stopping. What I would like to achieve is when the limit is reached (Max: 100), it would overwrite the index 0, 1, 2...

```
mapDataPayload[rcvData.Topic][0]
mapDataPayload[rcvData.Topic][1]
```

I tried to initialize the following with:

```
make(map[string][]*dataPayload, 100)

for {
    select {
    case rcvData := <-ch:
        mapDataPayload[rcvData.Topic][0] = &dataPayload{Message: rcvData.Message}
    }
}
```

But if I check the length it would return 0. Replacing append with direct initialization (mapDataPayload[rcvData.Topic][0]) would cause error immediately.

So, what I want to do is populate the map[string][]*dataPayload with a limit, for example this data:

```
{
  "test1": {
    "0": {
      "Message": "Heasdllo"
    },
    "1": {
      "Message": "Hel132lo"
    },
    "2": {
      "Message": "Hedsallo"
    }
  },
  "testanother": {
    "0": {
      "Message": "adsad"
    },
    "1": {
      "Message": "Helwqe2lo"
    },
    "2": {
      "Message": "Hel21321lo"
    },
    "3": {
      "Message": "Hel21321lo"
    }
  }
}
```

When it reaches the number 100 I want to go back to number 0, 1, 2...

Comment: Plain slices don't support such functionality. Take a look at https://golang.org/pkg/container/ring/, maybe it's what you need.

Comment: I will take a look on that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could implement a data structure for a circular buffer like this

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

type Circle struct  {
   Size int
   Contents []interface{}
   Pointer int
}

func (c *Circle) Setup(n int) {
   (*c).Size=n
   (*c).Contents=make([]interface{},n)
}

func (c *Circle) Add(value interface{}) {
   (*c).Contents[(*c).Pointer] = value
   (*c).Pointer = ((*c).Pointer+1) % (*c).Size
}


func main() {
        mapDataPayload := make(map[string]*Circle)
        mapDataPayload["aaa"]=&Circle{}
        mapDataPayload["aaa"].Setup(10)
    for i:=0; i<9999; i++ {
      mapDataPayload["aaa"].Add(i)
    }
    mapDataPayload["aaa"].Add("banana")
    fmt.Println(mapDataPayload["aaa"].Contents)

}
```

updated to use interface{} so any type of data can be used

Comment: I believe that this is what I am looking for, I will try to implement it and check if it is working as intended.

Comment: It worked however I am only able to store integer values on mapDataPayload["aaa"].Add(i) and I receive []byte which could be any type, could be an integer, string, ...

Comment: oh ok, you need to replace the ``Contents []int`` with ``Contents []interface{}``  I've updated the answer

Comment: For some reason the first position starts 0 (undefined), but when it reaches the end and starts again it is overwritten as expected. Its not a big deal to me starting in the position 1 instead of 0 but I just point it out for someone that find this answer useful.

Comment: yes, that was my fault.  Fixed in code snippet now.  Swap the lines in the func Add so the pointer is incremented after the insertion

Answer (score 0):

Use like this:

```
for {
    select {
    case rcvData := <-ch:

        _, exists := mapDataPayload[rcvData.Topic]
        if !exists {
            mapDataPayload[rcvData.Topic] = []*dataPayload{}
        }
        if len(mapDataPayload[rcvData.Topic]) < 100 {
            mapDataPayload[rcvData.Topic] = append(
                mapDataPayload[rcvData.Topic],
                &dataPayload{Message: rcvData.Message},
            )
        } else {
            mapDataPayload[rcvData.Topic][len(mapDataPayload[rcvData.Topic]) % 100] = &dataPayload{Message: rcvData.Message}
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This does not work as expected. size var is incrementing no mater the rcvData.Topic which is dynamic